# Error when trying to access image stored on server using Angular app

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework

I have a Django REST Framework application where the models have image field. The images uploaded are stored on a folder on the server. But when we try to access it using Angular we get an error.

Angular code:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getImage().subscribe((response) => console.log(response.size));
  }

  getImage() {
    return this.http
      .get('http://xxxx/media/images/categories/95_vtuvJuy.jpg', {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      })
      .pipe(
        map((response) => {
          return new File([response], 'myImage.png');
        })
      );
  }
}
```

[image]